# What is the easiest way to get list of all guild ids? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My question is simple, I was searching for this on the internet but i haven't found anything helpful.

Can someone tell me what is the easiest way to get `list` of all `bot.guilds` `id`s? Maybe you guys know how to get it as interger? It would be the best.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share your code/approches and tell us where you get stuck. Also have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `[guild.id for guild in client.guilds]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code should work:

```
for guild in client.guilds:
    print(guild.id)
```

You can use it on on ready event, or for a command.

Answer (score 3):

easy as this:

```
@client.command()
async def commandname(ctx):
    listofids = []
    for guild in client.guilds:
        listofids.append(guild.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready() :
    guilds = [guild.id for guild in client.guilds]
    print(f"The {client.user.name} bot is in {len(guilds)} Guilds.\nThe guilds ids list : {guilds}")

client.run("token here")
```